# Stop playback of an mp3 file as soon as the volume level of the mp3 file goes below a threshold

Tags: c#, audio, naudio

I want to play a mp3 file in c#. The form should have a start and stop button.

When the user clicks the stop button, playback will not stop immediately but when the current playback volume goes below a certain threshold, in other words, when "silence" occurs in the mp3 - file for a given minimum time.

What would be an efficient way to do this?

I need to know

1. Which dll/import to use to play the mp3 file
2. How to get the *current* volume level of the file being played using the same dll from "1." **as an integer, float or double**.

Having answers to those two questions I can go on on my own.

PS: I don't want to know where silence is in a file in general. I want a function that tells me whether right now there is silence. So I pass some stream's bytes to it and a threshold and it returns true or false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify what you are using to play MP3. But I'm using [BASS](http://www.un4seen.com/bass.html) for it. Your question was asked in their forum. Here [it is](http://www.un4seen.com/forum/?topic=13147.0). BTW, you may need [BASS .NET](http://www.un4seen.com/download.php?z/4/Bass24.Net.zip), which is a .NET wrapper for BASS, to use BASS with C#.

Edit due to change in question:

You can use bass.dll in the link I gave above. Download the .NET wrapper, add it to your references. Here is an example in VB 6. Just change the longs to integers and integers to shorts, the function names are the same. You should get the idea from here.

```
Public Sub GetSilenceLength(ByVal file As String, ByVal threshold As Long, ByRef startp As Long, ByRef endp As Long)
   Dim buf(50000) As Integer
   Dim count As Long, pos As Long
   Dim chan As Long
   Dim a As Long, b As Long
   Dim c As Long, d As Long
   count = 0

   chan = BASS_StreamCreateFile(BASSFALSE, file, 0, 0, BASS_STREAM_DECODE) 'create decoding channel

   If (chan = 0) Then Exit Sub

   Do
         b = BASS_ChannelGetData(chan, buf(0), 20000) 'decode some data
         b = b / 2 'bytes -> samples
         a = 0
         Do      'count silent samples
               a = a + 1
         Loop While ((a < b) And (Abs(buf(a)) <= threshold))
         count = count + (a * 2)
         If (a < b) Then 'sound has bagun
               'move back to a quieter sample (to avoid "click")
               Do
                     a = a - 1
                     count = count - 2
               Loop While ((a) And (Abs(buf(a)) > threshold / 4))
               Exit Do
         End If
   Loop While (BASS_ChannelIsActive(chan))

   startp = count

   pos = BASS_StreamGetLength(chan)
   Do
         pos = IIf(pos < 100000, 0, pos - 100000) 'step back a bit
         BASS_ChannelSetPosition chan, pos
         d = BASS_ChannelGetData(chan, buf(0), 100000) ' decode some data
         d = d / 2 'bytes -> samples
         c = d
         Do
               c = c - 1  'count silent samples
         Loop While (c > 0) And (Abs(buf(c)) <= threshold / 2) 'Here is the correction
         If (c > 0) Then   'sound has begun
               count = pos + c * 2
               Exit Do
         End If
   Loop While (pos > count)
   endp = count
   BASS_StreamFree (chan)
End Sub
```

Also if you want fade, thats another yet easy story.

Comment: I don't want to know where silence is in a file in general. I want a function that tells me whether right now there is silence. So I pass some stream's bytes to it and a threshold and it returns true or false.